# Can we control a terminal-window size from a '.desktop' file

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal, window, resize, .desktop

The .desktop file opens a python script in the terminal. (with 'Exec' and Terminal = true). Could any other parameters be included so as to open the gnome-terminal in a specific profile or a particular window size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it is not necessary to use `Terminal=true` in your .desktop file. To open your python script in gnome-terminal with a specific profile or a particular window size you can use:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --profile=Profile_name --geometry=widthxheight -e '/path/to/script.py'
```

You have more other options if you look at [`man gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html).

Also, be sure that you have this two lines at the end of your python script if you want to keep the terminal open after the execution of the script is finished:

```py
import os            # Use this line only if you have not already imported the os module
os.system("$SHELL")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call the terminal with `--geometry=widthxheight`

For example at command line:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=40x10
```

will open a terminal window with the above size (40x10)